# Are the gradient and derivative correctly written in this lecture note?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, proof-explanation, definition

I'm reading about the derivative of multivariable function:

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

First, the lecture note prove that the gradient of $f_{2}(x)=\frac{1}{2}\langle Q x, x\rangle \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is $$\nabla f_{2}(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(Q+Q^{\top}\right) x \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$$

Then they use this result and the chain rule to compute the derivative of $f_3:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R, \quad x \to \|x\|$.

**My questions:**

1. Because $\nabla \|x\| = \nabla \langle x,x \rangle = 2x$. I could not understand why the lecture note gives $D \|x\|^2 = (2x)^{\top}$ and it concludes that $D f_3(x) = \frac{x^{\top}}{\|x\|}$ and $\nabla f_{3}(x)=\frac{x}{\|x\|}$. How does the transpose operator come into the play?
2. From my understanding, $D f_3 (x) \in \mathcal L(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R)$. As such, should it be $D f_3 (x) = \langle \nabla f_{3}(x), \cdot\rangle$ rather than $\frac{x^{\top}}{\|x\|}$? Similarly, should it be $D \|x\|^2 = \langle 2x, \cdot\rangle$ rather than $2x^{\top}$?
3. I understand that $D f_3 (x)$ is a continuous linear map in $\mathcal L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R)$ such that $D f_3 (x) (\cdot) = \langle \nabla f_3(x), \cdot \rangle$. This kind of notation makes sense for me. As such, $Df_3(x)(v) = \langle \nabla f_3(x), v \rangle = \left \langle \dfrac{x^\top}{\|x\|}, v \right\rangle = \dfrac{x^\top}{\|x\|}\cdot v$. On the other hand, the way of writing $Df_3(x) = \dfrac{x^\top}{\|x\|}$ is very confusing to me. It suggests me that $Df_3(x) (v) = \dfrac{x^\top}{\|x\|}$ for any vector $v$.

It seems to me that the gradient and derivative are mixed up in this lecture note.

Could you please elaborate on my confusion? Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you are considering vectors as column matrices, it seems to me that $Df_{3}(x)$ should be its transpose when viewed as a matrix. As $x$ in a matrix with $n$ rows and $1$ column, then in order to $Df_{3}$ to be a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, it should be a matrix with 1 row and $n$ columns.

Comment: Hi @Willy.K, if $D f_3 = \frac{x^{\top}}{\|x\|}$ then it would not be a linear map.

Comment: It might be a matter of notation. If we are seeing $Df_{3}$ as a linear transformation with respect to the fixed point $x$, it is. But I understand your notation means $x$ is arbitrary, right?

Comment: Hi @Willy.K, I'm sorry, I meant $D f_3 (x)= \frac{x^{\top}}{\|x\|}$. In this notation, $D f_3 (x)$ is a fixed value and $D f_3 (x)= \frac{x^{\top}}{\|x\|} \notin \mathcal L(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R)$. How could it be possible?

Comment: I am a little confused as well haha. But, suppose $\pi^{i}$ is the $i$-th projection map, $\pi^{i}(x)=x_{i}$. Then, $f(x)=||x||^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\pi^{i}\pi^{i}(x)$. The derivative of $||\cdot||^{2}$ at a point $a \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ should be, using the sum and product rule for the derivative (viewed as a linear map) $Df(a) = 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}\pi^{i}(a)\pi^{i}$ .If we now associate, to each $\pi^{i}$ the column matrix with entry 1 in the $i$−th entry and zero othe rwise, we have a linear map such as $2a^{T}$.The same reasoning should carry for $||x||$, shouldnt it?

Comment: @Willy.K I feel that being your way gets things more complicated :(

Comment: Yes, you are probably right. My point here is following. The derivative is a linear transformation, this linear transformation depends on the point you are considering the derivative. Thats why I wrote the derivative at $a \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. This leads to a linear transformation that depends on $a$, because $a$ is fixed. For a general $x$, this should work the same way.

Comment: Two comments. First, you should have $\nabla \|x\|^2$, not $\nabla \|x\|$ in your first line. Second, you're confusing the linear map at $x$ and its value on a vector, $v$, say. $Df_3(x) = x^\top/\|x\|$ and $Df_3(x)(v) = (x^\top v)/\|x\| = (x\cdot v)/\|x\|$.

Comment: Hi @TedShifrin, I understand that $D f_3 (x)$ is a continuous linear map in $\mathcal L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R)$ such that $D f_3 (x) (\cdot) = \langle \nabla f_3(x), \cdot \rangle$. This kind of notation makes sense for me. As such, $Df_3(x)(v) = \langle \nabla f_3(x), v \rangle = \left \langle \dfrac{x^\top}{\|x\|}, v \right\rangle  = \dfrac{x^\top}{\|x\|}\cdot v$. On the other hand, the way of writing $Df_3(x) = \dfrac{x^\top}{\|x\|}$ is very confusing to me. It suggests me that $Df_3(x) (v) = \dfrac{x^\top}{\|x\|}$ for any vector $v$.

Comment: No, no, no. Why should it suggest that? This is why some texts write $Df_x$ to indicate the point the derivative is computed at, saving the parentheses for evaluating on the vector.

Comment: Hi @TedShifrin, When I see a function $f$ is written as $f = a$, It means to me that $f=a$ for any $x$ in the domain of $f$. I'm so sorry, but I'm self-learning. This is the first time I'm exposed to multivariable calculus.

Comment: You might find my lectures on YouTube helpful if you're learning rigorous multivariable calculus. This exact question appears as one of my favorite examples. You can find the link in my profile.

Comment: Thank you @TedShifrin, May I ask if from which day of lecture, this question appears?

Comment: Good question. Try 3500 lectures 22 (anteater discussion) and 26. Others may be helpful generally for you!

Comment: It's really a great resource. I will consult your video lectures frequently @TedShifrin!

Comment: @TedShifrin, I'm actually watching Lecture 21 ^^